David Pines demon (Distinct Electron Motion) particle
What was the motivation for David Pines' prediction that electrons could combine and behave as a composite particle (plasmons) that are massless, neutral, and does not interact with light?
It was thought to be impossible to detect until this phenomenon was observed in 2023 within the material of strontium ruthenate.
I am curious as to the reasoning that lead Pines to hypothesize that electrons could behave this way 67 years before its confirmation?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
